# Returning an optional value and an error

Tags: go

What's the best signature for a function that returns an optional value and a possible error?

For example:

```
func findColor(name string) (RGB, error) {
    ...
}
```

(The empty RGB value is black, a valid color, so you can't use it to infer that no value was found. Assume the error might come from something like a database connection.)

The two options that seem best are a boolean return value:

```
func findColor(name string) (RGB, bool, error) {
    ...
}

c, ok, err := findColor(myname)

if !ok {
    ...
} else if err != nil {
    ...
}

...
```

Or a special error value:

```
var ColorNotFound = errors.New(...)

func findColor(name string) (RGB, error) {
    ...
}

c, err := findColor(...)

if err == ColorNotFound {
    ...
} else if err != nil {
    ...
}

...
```

(Making special errors seems like a pain.)

What's the most idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The convention in Go is to return `(value, error)` and if `error != nil` then `value` is (or may be) invalid.

If you have special errors you need to do something with (like [io.EOF](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#pkg-variables)) then making a specific error is normal practice.  So I would say your 3rd example is the most idiomatic, if you want to do something different for `ColorNotFound`.

```
var ColorNotFound = errors.New(...)

func findColor(name string) (RGB, error) {
    // ...
}

c, err := findColor(...)

if err == ColorNotFound {
    // Do something special if ColorNotFound...
} else if err != nil {
    // Some other kind of error...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make `findColor` return `*RGB` and then compare it to nil:

```
c, err := findColor(name)
if err != nil { /* Handle error. */ }
if c == nil { /* Handle no color. */ }
```

This is unsafe though, since if you try to call methods on a `nil` pointer, they can cause a panic.

I'd recommend sticking with a special `ErrColorNotFound` approach.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to emphasis the "_can_" part. Just in case you didn't: http://play.golang.org/p/n-DHa5GVJI

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, I added "can" because methods may not panic when the receiver is `nil`. If *all* methods of your `RGB` type can handle this situation, and there are no assumptions that `*RGB` is always non-nil anywhere in the code, you should be fine. Otherwise, use an error.